# How to resolve `error starting spoon shell`?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, apache-hop

I'm porting Pentaho kettle to apache hop and I followed the steps given in this [document](https://hop.apache.org/dev-manual/latest/porting-kettle-plugins.html), after changing the dependencies build was successful but got an error while starting spoon.sh file

Below was the error I caught when I run spoon.sh

```
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General - ERROR (version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, build 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT from 2021-12-01 07.33.36 by ****) : Error starting Spoon shell
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General - ERROR (version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, build 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT from 2021-12-01 07.33.36 by ****) : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.init(Spoon.java:870)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createContents(Spoon.java:9352)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9383)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:711)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General - Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ui/laf, locale en_IN
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1581)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1091)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.XulSpoonResourceBundle.<clinit>(XulSpoonResourceBundle.java:69)
2021/12/01 13:08:04 - General -     ... 11 more
```

Has anyone run into this before? Do you have a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but Apache Hop does not have a spoon.sh file. To start the GUI you have to use the hop-gui.sh file.

It seems you have copied over the spoon.sh file?

If you are porting over a step/job entry to a Hop Transform or Action there is a sample repository available [here](https://github.com/project-hop/hop-plugin-sample) you can use the code in there as a base to see what has to be done to get everything running in Hop.

If you have specific questions you can also contact the developers on the mailing list